# How to integrate the .aar file with ionic application

Tags: android, ionic-framework

anyone help me how to integrate the .aar file with Ionic application.I referred so  many tutorials but not found exact answer help me how to create cordova plugin and how to integrate the .aar file of android to the ionic application with brief explanation

Answer (score 3):

As per my experience, you need to create a custom plugin and use your **.aar** file in your custom plugin.

Follow the below steps to use ur **.aar** file in Ionic project.

**Step 1:** Create a plugin.

You can use [Plugman](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman) to create your custom plugin.

**Step 2:** Setup All Android dependencies

Setup all required dependency for your **.aar** file to support native dependencies through Gradle.

**Step 3:** Configure APIs

Need to define required wrapper API in your **.JS** file which is exported to the Cordova application.

By these 3 steps, you will get your **.aar** functionality through custom plugin wrapper and expose all required methods for Ionic app.

Find below useful links to achieve your requirements.

- [Barcode AAR ref](https://www.codepool.biz/cordova-plugin-android-aar-barcode.html)
- [Building Cordova Plugin](https://medium.com/hypertrack/building-a-cordova-plugin-for-your-native-sdk-174f1d7d20ca)
- [Plugman](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugman)
- [Android app .aar setup for ionic](http://aarphonegapplugin.blogspot.com/2015/09/aar-file-with-phonegapcordova-plugin.html)

I hope you will find the above answer & link helpful.