# Use .aar file in Ionic application

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a Java package .aar file. I need to use it in Ionic application. I try to create a Cordova plugin and add an aahe file in it.But don't have proper idea about it.

Do anyone suggest how to do it?

Any link?

Comment: Tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280215/how-to-integrate-the-aar-file-with-ionic-application ??

Comment: Hi Dan, I follow your steps but got the error while building apk file.=>Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
              
                at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
        > Failed to execute aapt

        BUILD FAILED in 17s