# Add AAR file in ionic 3 application by creating custom plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Using this link 
[How to integrate the .aar file with ionic application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280215/how-to-integrate-the-aar-file-with-ionic-application)
I create a custom plugin (bar code Scanner) for my ionic application & add an aar file successfully but I got an error during ionic cordova build .

> (truncated) ... ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>                   at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>                   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
>                   at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
>                   at
>           org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>                   at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>           Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>           com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>                   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>                   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
>                   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>                   at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
>                   ... 48 more
>           Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check
>           logs for details
>                   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
>                   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
>                   at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
>                   at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>                   ... 1 more
>           Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
>                   at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
>                   at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
>                   at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
>                   at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > Failed to execute aapt
```